# AndroidHttpAsync not working at oncreate method

Tags: android, android-async-http

Whenever I use `AsyncHttpClient` in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`, `onSuccess()` method never used.

I put a break point, than debug... Never visit to break point if the break point is in the `onSuccess()` method, but when I put a button, after button click, it works?

I need to get values in `onCreate()` methods...

```
String url = "http://192.168.56.1:8080/restfulwssample/rest/examples/wsetkinlikgetir/";
    url = url + eposta;

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

    client.get(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            try {
                arr = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    String ali = jsonobject.getString("etkinlikAdi");
                    etkinlikAdlari[i] = jsonobject.getString("etkinlikTarihi");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                              String content) {
            // When Http response code is '404'
            if (statusCode == 404) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "404", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
            // When Http response code is '500'
            else if (statusCode == 500) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "500", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
            // When Http response code other than 404, 500
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Else", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Show your Activity code.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, i can share my activity code

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity{

JSONArray arr = null;
String[] etkinlikAdlari;
String eposta;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_count_down_temp);


    String url = "http://192.168.56.1:8080/restfulwssample/rest/examples/wsetkinlikgetir/";
    url = url + eposta;

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

    client.get(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            try {
                arr = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    String ali = jsonobject.getString("etkinlikAdi");
                    etkinlikAdlari[i] = jsonobject.getString("etkinlikTarihi");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                              String content) {
            // When Http response code is '404'
            if (statusCode == 404) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "404", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
            // When Http response code is '500'
            else if (statusCode == 500) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "500", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
            // When Http response code other than 404, 500
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Else", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}